# PostgreSQL database with 9000 tables continuously grow in memory usage

Tags: postgresql, memory, time-series-database

I have a PostgreSQL database that I use to store time-series (finance) data. each table contains the same table schema but has a different name based on the market pair and timeframe.

Ex. I have tables called `candles_btc_usdt_one_minute`, `candles_eth_usdt_one_hour`, `candles_eth_usdt_one_week`, etc.

These tables sum up to around 9000 tables in total.

Note that I know about `TimescaleDB` and `InfluxDB`, I already tested both and will post a reason I'm not using them at the end of this post.

So, since this is time-series data, it means that I'm only doing `INSERT` write operations and very rarely some `SELECT` to retrieve some data.

My issue is that the database memory usage seems to grow infinitely until I get an OOM crash. I configured my `postgresql.conf` using solutions as `PGTune` to a system with 1GB of RAM, 6 cores, and 120 connections and I limited my docker container to 4GB and still got an OOM after around one day with the system on.

I also tried other configs as 4GB of ram and 8GB in the container but PostgreSQL never respects the limit stipulated by the config and keeps using more and more RAM.

Is this the expected behavior? Maybe PostgreSQL has some other obscure config I can use to limit the memory usage in cases where there is a huge number of tables.. I'm not sure..

The reason I'm guessing this issue has something to do with my high number of tables is because the opened connections from my connection pool keep growing in memory usage faster at the start of my system (the first hours) and then the growth gets slower (but never stops).

That behavior reflects my `INSERT` intervals when hitting the tables.

For example, a table with a timeframe `five_minutes` means that every five minutes I will insert a new row to it, which means that I'm accessing these tables for the first time faster when the system starts than tables with higher timeframes as `one_hour`, etc.

And monitoring the memory growth, it seems that the connection process grows a little bit when it accesses a new table for the first time.

So, assuming this is right, it would mean that after some months, all the connections would have accessed all the tables at least one time and memory growth would stop. The problem with that is that I don't know how much memory this would use at the end and it's not ideal since trying to limit the memory via `postgresql.conf` becomes meaningless.

Here is the schema for one of the tables (as I said before, all tables has the same columns, index, etc):

```
data_db_prod=# \d+ candles_one_minute_btc_usdt
                                   Table "public.candles_one_minute_btc_usdt"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              | 
 open      | numeric                     |           | not null |         | main    |              | 
 close     | numeric                     |           | not null |         | main    |              | 
 high      | numeric                     |           | not null |         | main    |              | 
 low       | numeric                     |           | not null |         | main    |              | 
 volume    | numeric                     |           | not null |         | main    |              | 
Indexes:
    "candles_one_minute_btc_usdt_timestamp_desc_index" btree ("timestamp" DESC)
    "candles_one_minute_btc_usdt_timestamp_index" btree ("timestamp")
Access method: heap
```

### About other solutions

As I said before, I already tried `TimescaleDB` and `InfluxDB`.

For `TimescaleDB` I would be able to use a single `candles` table and create 2 partitions to store the market pair and the timeframe, fixing the high number of tables and probably the RAM issue I'm having, but I cannot use this because `TimescaleDB` uses too much storage, so I would need to use their compression feature, but a compressed hypertable doesn't allow write operations, meaning that to be able to do a backfill (which I do often) I would need to basically decompress the whole database each time.

For `InfluxDB` the issue is simply because they don't support any `numeric`/`decimal` type, and I cannot lose precision using `double`.

Feel free to suggest some other alternative I'm not aware of that would fit nicely into my use case if there is one.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that information, I'm running PostgreSQL 13.1

Comment: Just curious:  "but I cannot use this because TimescaleDB uses too much storage" --> (uncompressed) TimescaleDB shouldn't consume any more storage than Postgres, so I'm confused what you are seeing?  Is it just the default index overhead, which you can turn off?

(Timescale person here)

Comment: Hmm, last time I checked the same database consumed around 300GB in TimescaleDB and 70GB in PostgreSQL, I also remember that somewhere in the TimescaleDB documentation there was something about this that recommended enabling compression to mitigate it.

Comment: Not sure why you don't use one table with list partitioning. The per table, per connection overhead is killing you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Brian, I never used Postgres partitioning, so I was not aware if it would help someway, I will test it and see what changes.

Comment: So, I tested Postgres partitioning, but the memory usage still goes above the limit... I think it does have something to do with the number of connections as @jjanes said, I will try PGBouncer so I can lower the number of connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each backend (the process a connection is connected to) keeps a cache of data on every object it has touched.  There is no provision for expiring this cache, so it does indeed grow for every object it has ever used.

Why does your connection pooler maintain 120 connections, or 20 for every CPU?  This seems like a ridiculous number, especially considering you already know you have memory problems.

I find that it uses about 6.7kB for every table (with two indexes) which it touches.  I used the 'max resident' line from the stats collected by `log_executor_stats=on`.  That isn't really suitable for use in production, but I don't know what to use in that case.

Comment: The reason is because since I insert new data at specific times (every 5 minutes for 5 minute timeframe, every 15 minutes for 15 minutes timeframe and so on), normally all my connections are idle and at these times I get a lot of queries at the same time to do new data insertion.

I think I can lower that number a bit or even try using PGBouncer to see if helps, but I didn't try it yet because I was not sure if this was the real issue.

Comment: So, considering this is the case, is it possible to calculate how much this cache can reach so I can better preview how much my database will consume in RAM?

Comment: Also jjanes, do you know if it is possible to get some telemetry or some other way to get the usage of this (and others) cache? I would like to be able to see it better so I can be certain where is the issue.

Comment: In the end, the number of connections was indeed the reason for the increase in my ram, the solution for me was to use PGBouncer so my app can still has more than100 connections but PostgreSQL itself only has 20.